# Unable to retrieve unlimited number of record via API

Tags: activecollab

We are struggling to mine all time records for this year via API.

We have tried to include the `:dont_limit_result` GET variable and set it to 1, however it did not help us.

The version that we use is ACTIVE COLLAB 5.11.0, the URL we are hitting: `projects?dont_limit_result=1&page=$page`

Please give me some advise on how to proceed.

Comment: Which version of Active Collab are you using? Active Collab 5 does not support that argument, while v4 does, so version number is relevant here. Also, tell me which API URL are you hitting with a request. Please update your question, and we'll answer ASAP.

Comment: The version that we use is ACTIVE COLLAB 5.11.0, the URL we are hitting: projects?dont_limit_result=1&page=$page

Comment: Answer posted. If it helps, please accept the answer so other visitors to SO know that it is a correct answer (or suggest how answer can be improved).

Comment: Both of curl commands return empty array "[]" tried with curl also with php api

Answer (score 0):

Most of API responses are paginated, and pagination can't be turned off using a GET switch. Instead, you should check following headers:

- `X-Angie-PaginationCurrentPage` - indicates current page
- `X-Angie-PaginationItemsPerPage` - indicates number of items per page
- `X-Angie-PaginationTotalItems` - indicates number of items in the entire data set.

and walk through pages until you reach the end of data set.

Another option is to give project's filter a try. Here's an example request that will return all projects:

```
curl -H "X-Angie-AuthApiToken: YOUR-API-TOKEN" "http://your.activecollab.com/api/v1/reports/run?type=ProjectsFilter"
```

This one will return all active projects:

```
curl -H "X-Angie-AuthApiToken: YOUR-API-TOKEN" "http://your.activecollab.com/api/v1/reports/run?type=ProjectsFilter&completed_on_filter=is_not_set"
```

Comment: Both of curl commands return empty array "[]" tried with curl also with php api

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the php API wrapper 3.0 - how do i get the headers back to know there are more pages and then what is the correct form of the query to get further pages?

For example my basic query is:

$timeRecords = $client->get('projects/22/time-records')->getJson();

to get time records - but this only returns 100 and there are more!

Thanks,

P